# How to succesfully cache most used data(image and texts) in react-native

Tags: image, react-native, caching, text

Hello I'm developing an app similar to Alibaba market but I need to cache home page with all the data and images and some searches too(the last ones). My question is What is the best architectural way of cache in this kind of app

Comment: you can use redux-persist

Comment: <Image> component can cache images. Here is official docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#cache-control-ios-only